# Using html MouseOver Event

Tags: html, image, mouseover, chm

I have a very peculiar requirement and I am not an HTML expert. I need to create a CHM (Compiled HTML File) in which I want to use an image (a single screenshot) that will have parts of the image linked to other sections in the help file. In other words I want to hover the mouse to individual regions in the single screenshot to link to other parts of the help file.

Just for information the screenshot is a shot of various buttons and checkboxes that are a part of the application.

I do not wish to break up the single image into multiple images and then link each image to another part of the help file (that explains the function of the image). I think that is very much possible and not a problem at all.

If you can just in brief explain how this can be done or provide me a link I would be grateful.

Comment: can an image map be used within a chm file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Image Map for this. You basically have a normal image and then place various invisible shapes over the image. You can then use all the shapes for hover and click events.

With some googling I found this: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/images_famsupp_220.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an HTML image map, which you can create online [here](http://www.image-maps.com/). An HTML image map is a set of tags describing various regions of an image that can have links of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTML Image Map:

[Creating HTML Image Maps](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't those called "image maps"? HTML has a tag called `<area>` (and `<map>` itself) which allows you to do this.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an image map for this. If you want to get a bit fancy and have rollover's for this you could think about using the ImageMapster jQuery plugin.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/usa.html